# RSelenium - downloading a file with phantom.js

Tags: r, phantomjs, rselenium

Using `RSelenium` I can download a file from a webpage using a connection via a Firefox browser with the following formula:

```
csv = remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', "a[ng-click*=download]")
remDr$executeScript("arguments[0].click();", list(csv))
```

When I try to replicate the process with phantomjs browser nothing happens.   Guessing maybe no download directory is set, I've tried:

```
remDr$extraCapabilities = makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.dir = "/download/path"))
```

Still nothing happens.  Grateful for an idea what needs to happen to get this to work.

---

**Edit.**

I should add the following report during setup, which may or may not be relevant, although it doesn't appear to stop the page connection or element selection:

```
> pJS = phantom()
[ERROR - 2016-03-17T17:54:08.914Z] GhostDriver - main.fail - {"line":85,"sourceURL":"phantomjs://code/main.js","stack":"global code@phantomjs://code/main.js:85:56"}

  phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
```

Comment: what is `pJS = phantom()` doing? I normally only have to specify the browser in the `remoteDriver()` call: `remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs")`

Comment: Well yes it seems to work to a degree without it.  But is it in [official documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-headless.html#id1a)..

Comment: huh... well, I've never used it ;-)

Comment: @jdharrison Wonder if you have any advice to offer?

Answer (score 5):

phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error

This error commonly happens when you run selenium server and phantomjs in the same port

Comment: I have the same error. What other port could I use? Any?

Comment: Thanks this does prevent that error :) Doesn't solve my download problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm it seems phanrom.js [doesn't support file download](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10052).